# Which gridview of a list fires an event

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a `List` of `GridView` and I want to add the same `CellEndEdit` event at each `GridView`.

it is possible to determine which gridview fire the `CellEndEdit` event ?

```
lst.Add(new RadGridView());
RadGridView radgridview= lst.Last();
radgridview.CellEndEdit += new GridViewCellEventHandler(radgridview_CellEndEdit);

private void radgridview_CellEndEdit(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //I want to know here which radgridview is modified
}
```

Comment: The sender parameter is the RadGridView that has raised the CellEndEdit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard event pattern passes the source of the event as argument in the `sender` parameter. So you can simply cast `sender` to `RadGridView` and have the relevant instance:

```
private void radgridview_CellEndEdit(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    RadGridView sendingGridView = sender as RadGridView;
    if (sendingGridView == null || !lst.Contains(sendingGridView))
        return; // just to be sure
}
```

---

Obviously in this case the `sender` is a `GridViewEditManager`, so you may get your `RadGridView` like this:

```
private void radgridview_CellEndEdit(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewEditManager manager = sender as GridViewEditManager;
    RadGridView sendingGridView = manager?.GridViewElement?.GridControl;

    if (sendingGridView == null || !lst.Contains(sendingGridView))
        return; // just to be sure
}
```

Comment: can you debug and find out what `sender` really is? maybe it's the cell and you can get the gridview from it.

Comment: sender is GridViewEditManager

Comment: @llwynrt updated my answer, you can get the original `RadGridView` through the properties of the `GridViewEditManager`.